# Back from fragment to Activity onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

My question is that, i've one activity and one fragment,from activity open that fragment but when i pressed back button it close application.
i try with this code.

### for open fragment.

```
 case R.id.button_contact:
         Fragment fragment = new FragmentContact();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment).addToBackStack("Frag1").commit();
                break;
```

### for back button.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate("Frag1",0);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: comment out  `super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: removing getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate("Frag1",0); will be better , because you have already added the fragment to backstack and it will be automatically popped  out from backstack when back button is pressed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you just want to remove the fragment and have the activity remain?

In that case modify your onBackPressed method to be

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Frag1") != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate("Frag1",0);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

This will remove the fragment from the activity if it is added and if it isn't, then the back button will act as normal and destroy the activity.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line from onBackPressed().

```
  getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate("Frag1",0);
```

Its work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. It will work with your stack:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
  super.onBackPressed();
} else {
  getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

This piece of code will pop the stack if there is any fragment. Otherwise the back button will close the activity

Answer (score 1):

What these two lines are doing:

```
1). getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate("Frag1",0);
    As you are adding you fragment in activity backstack, so when you are calling on back press,
    it remove fragment from stack, now in your stack activity is left, means stack size is one.

2). super.onBackPressed();
I think you  are aware of calling super.onbackpress funcionality, here it will finish
 your activity and stack size is 0 now, and app will close immidately if stack size is 0.
```

so you have to remove super.onbackpress() Method.